# Wix "Unable to load tool from path"

Tags: visual-studio, wix

I'm trying to create a WIX setup MSI for a Visual Studio service project but I'm struggling with harvesting the files using Heat. I created a WIX (v4)setup project, added a reference to the source project, added this to the Setup.wixproject:

```
<HeatDirectory Directory="..ImportService\bin\$(Configuration)" 
               VerboseOutput="true" 
               PreprocessorVariable="var.SourceDir"
               OutputFile="HeatGeneratedFileList.wxs" 
               ComponentGroupName="HeatGenerated" 
               DirectoryRefId="INSTALLFOLDER" 
               AutogenerateGuids="true" 
               ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" 
               SuppressFragments="true" 
               SuppressRegistry="true" 
               SuppressRootDirectory="true" />
```

and added **SourceDir=$(SoluctionDir)ImportService\bin\$(Configuration)** (as per [this example](http://geoffwebbercross.blogspot.com/2013/06/using-wix-heat-to-harvest-files-for-wix.html)) as preprocessor variable in the setup project. When I build the project I get:

```
Unable to load tool from path file:///C:\Users\<Username>\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\ImportService\Import Setup\Heat.exe.  Consider setting the ToolPath parameter to $(WixToolPath).
```

I don't understand why I get that error. The ToolPath in my configuration is already set to $(WixToolPath). What am I not doing correctly?

Comment: can you add the contents of your .wixproj file here?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. try uninstalling all the tool set versions and just install toolset 4

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to resolve this?

Comment: I was getting the same error and did the workaround listed in this [link](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/6636) adding this `RunAsSeparateProcess="true"` and it started working